# Regex questions

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get some text from a large text file, the text I'm looking for is:

Type:Production
Color:Red

I pass the whole text in the following method to get (Type:Production , Color:Red)

```
  private static void FindKeys(IEnumerable<string> keywords, string source)
    {
        var found = new Dictionary<string, string>(10);
        var keys = string.Join("|", keywords.ToArray());
        var matches = Regex.Matches(source, @"(?<key>" + @"\B\s" + keys + @"\B\s" + "):",
                              RegexOptions.Singleline);

        foreach (Match m in matches)
        {
            var key = m.Groups["key"].ToString();
            var start = m.Index + m.Length;
            var nx = m.NextMatch();
            var end = (nx.Success ? nx.Index : source.Length);
            found.Add(key, source.Substring(start, end - start));

        }

        foreach (var n in found)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key={0}, Value={1}", n.Key, n.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

My problems are the following:

1. The search returns _Type: as well, where I only need Type:
2. The search return Color:Red/n/n/n/n/n (with the rest of the text, where I only need Color:Red

So, basically:
- How can I force Regex to get the exact match for Type and ignore _Type
- How to get only the text after : and ignore /n/n/ and any other text

I hope this is clear

Thanks,

Comment: What's your input (`string source`)?

Comment: What text is before 'Type:' ? Is it the beginning of a line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex currently looks like this:

```
(?<key>\B\sWord1|Word2|Word3\B\s):
```

I see the following issues here:

- First, `Word1|Word2|Word3` should be put in parenthesis. Otherwise, it will search for `\B\sWord1` or `Word2` or `Word3\B\s`, which is not what you want (I guess).
- Why `\B\s`? A non-boundary followed by a whitespace? That doesn't make sense. I guess you want just `\b` (= word boundary). There's no need to use it in the end, because the colon already constitutes a word boundary.

So, I would suggest to use the following. It will fix the `_Type` problem, because there is no word boundary between `_` and `Type` ([since `_` is considered to be a word character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter)).

```
\b(?<key>Word1|Word2|Word3):
```

If the text following the key is always just a single word, I'd match it in the regex as well: (`\s*` allows for whitespace after the colon, I don't know if you need this. `\w+` ensures that only word characters -- i.e. no line breaks etc. -- are matched as the value.)

```
\b(?<key>Word1|Word2|Word3):\s*(?<value>\w+)
```

Then you just need to iterate through all the matches and extract the `key` and `value` groups. No need for any string operations or index arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you have:

- Pairs of key:values
- Each pair is separated by a space
- Within each pair, the key and value is separated by “:”

Then I would **not use regex at all**.   I would:

- use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)(' ') to get an array of pairs
- loop over all the pairs
- use String.Split(':') to get the key and value from each pair

Comment: I almost always prefer using regular expressions to splitting, it's much more concise (when done correctly). But this is a good solution for someone who does not know and does not wish to learn regular expressions.

Comment: @Josh, the problem with regular expressions is even if you know then well, will everyone else that has to work on the source code?

Comment: My answer would be they "should" but that's just because I'm a fan.